# Is there a way to identify that a Disk is removable ?

Tags: automated-testing

On windows XP/7, is there a way to identify from a script (never mind the script language being used) that a disk is not a network or fixed drive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This VBS script will do it:

```
dim filesys
set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set drv = filesys.GetDrive("C")
 select case drv.DriveType 
   case 0: drtype = "Unknown" 
   case 1: drtype = "Removable" 
   case 2: drtype = "Fixed" 
   case 3: drtype = "Network" 
   case 4: drtype = "CD-ROM" 
   case 5: drtype = "RAM Disk"  
end select
 MsgBox "The specified drive is a " & drtype & " type disk."
```

Reference - [DevGuru](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/drive_drivetype.html)

Comment: +1 for a concise and useful little piece of code.  Sticking this in my code library.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you might do this using WinTask and the Win32 API GetDriveTypeA.

```
'
' GetDriveType
'
' Author: Joe Strazzere
'

dim a as unsigned    
dr$ = inputbox$("Enter the drive","GetDriveType","C:")    
a   = External("kernel32","GetDriveTypeA",dr$)

Select Case a

case 1    
  msgbox("Drive "+dr$+" was not found!",0,"GetDriveType")

case 2    
  msgbox("Drive "+dr$+" is a removable drive",0,"GetDriveType")

case 3    
  msgbox("Drive "+dr$+" is a fixed drive",0,"GetDriveType")

case 4    
  msgbox("Drive "+dr$+" is a network drive",0,"GetDriveType")

case 5    
  msgbox("Drive "+dr$+" is a CD-ROM drive",0,"GetDriveType")

case 6    
  msgbox("Drive "+dr$+" is a RAM drive",0,"GetDriveType")

case else    
  msgbox("I just don't know!",0,"GetDriveType")

endselect
```

http://strazzere.blogspot.com/2005/01/wintask-getdrivetype.html